# How to convert postgreSQL query to BigQuery?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

I have legasy Postgre query and i need to convert it to BigQuery script because now all the data based in BQ.

```
    SELECT to_timestamp(call.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)        AS call_ts,
           call.call_type                                                     AS typez,
           call.jk                                                            AS call_nb_name,
           call.sale_type                                                     AS cost,
           call.partner                                                       AS call_partner,
           call.call_state                                                    AS call_sell_status,
           to_timestamp(click.event_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text) AS click_ts,
           click.campaign,
           click.medium,
           click.source,
           click."OS"                                                         AS device_category,
           click.event_name                                                   AS event_label,
           NULL::text                                                         AS event_category,
           CASE
               WHEN regexp_match(click.region, 'MOSOBL'::text) IS NOT NULL THEN 'MOS'::text
               WHEN regexp_match(click.region, 'LENOBL'::text) IS NOT NULL THEN 'SP'::text
               ELSE NULL::text
               END                                                            AS click_region,
           call.city                                                          AS call_region,
           click."newBuilding_name"                                           AS click_nb_name
    FROM "username"."lost_calls" call
             LEFT JOIN "username"."call_track" click
                       ON to_timestamp(call.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text) >
                          to_timestamp(click.event_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text) AND
                          to_timestamp(click.event_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text) >
                          (to_timestamp(call.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text) - '02:00:00'::interval)
    WHERE click.medium !~~ 'test%'::text
      AND call.partner !~~ '%VAS%'::text
```

I managed to rewrite some of it, but still get zero results
Here is what i have now

```
SELECT timestamp(call.date_time)                                              AS call_ts,
           call.call_type                                                     AS typez,
           call.jk                                                            AS call_nb_name,
           call.sale_type                                                     AS cost,
           call.partner                                                       AS call_partner,
           call.call_state                                                    AS call_sell_status,
           timestamp(click.event_timestamp)                                   AS click_ts,
           click.campaign,
           click.medium,
           click.source,
           click.OS                                                           AS device_category,
           click.event_name                                                   AS event_label,
           NULL                                                               AS event_category,
           CASE
               WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(click.region, 'MOSOBL') IS NOT NULL THEN 'MOS'
               WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(click.region, 'LENOBL') IS NOT NULL THEN 'SP'
               ELSE NULL
               END                                                            AS click_region,
           call.city                                                          AS call_region,
           click.newBuilding_name                                             AS click_nb_name
    FROM `myproject.dataset.lost_calls` as call
             LEFT JOIN `myproject.dataset.call_track` as click
                       ON call.date_time > click.event_timestamp
                       AND click.event_timestamp = call.date_time
                       AND TIMESTAMP(click.event_timestamp) > TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP(call.date_time), interval 2 HOUR) 
    WHERE click.medium LIKE 'test%'
        AND call.partner LIKE '%VAS%'
```

My bet that problem is in LEFT JOIN, but me knolage in sql is nat the best to figure it out.
Also need to mention that now all dates already in `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` format but scheme says that it is string

Comment: In your Postgres query, you use `!~~` which I interpret as `NOT LIKE`, but you are using `LIKE` in your BQ query.

Comment: Did the comment above work for you? If not can you provide a complete sample data so the community easily reproduce the issues?